# Generating custom pyunit report

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I am trying to generate a custom pyunit test suite execution report, but hitting with a 'no attributue' error.

```
import json
import unittest
import sys

class MyTestResult(unittest._TextTestResult):
    def addSuccess(self, test):
        TestResult.addSuccess(self, test)
    def addError(self, test, err):
        TestResult.addError(self, test, err)
    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        TestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)

class MyTestRunner(unittest.TextTestRunner):
    def _makeResult(self, verbosity):
        return MyTestResult(self.stream, self.descriptions, verbosity)

class TestServer(unittest.TestCase):
    def testFunction1(self):
        res = True
        self.assertTrue(res, "test case failed")
    def testFunction2(self):
        res = 5
        self.assertEqual(res, 5)
    def testFunction3(self):
        res = True
        self.assertEqual(res, True, 'test case failed')
    def testFunction4(self):
        res = False
        self.assertEqual(res, True, 'test case failed')

# Create an instance of each test case.
testCase1 = TestServer('testFunction1')
testCase2 = TestServer('testFunction2')
testCase3 = TestServer('testFunction3')
testCase4 = TestServer('testFunction4')

# Add test cases to the test suite.
testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
testSuite.addTest(testCase1)
testSuite.addTest(testCase2)
testSuite.addTest(testCase3)
testSuite.addTest(testCase4)

# Execute the test suite.
testRunner = unittest.MyTestRunner(verbosity=2)
testRunner.run(testSuite)
```

The error I am getting is below. I also need some help to customize my final test report so that I can add some additional information than the one pyunit generates. What should I implement inside 'MyTestResult' class more?

```
bash-3.2$ python myreport.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myreport.py", line 45, in <module>
    testRunner = unittest.MyTestRunner(verbosity=2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyTestRunner'
```

Additionally, I am looking for some suggestion to modify the test report, which is coming as below by default.

```
bash-3.2$ python myreport.py
testFunction1 (__main__.TestServer) ... ERROR
testFunction2 (__main__.TestServer) ... ok
testFunction3 (__main__.TestServer) ... ok
testFunction4 (__main__.TestServer) ... FAIL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should be replaced with:

```
testRunner = MyTestRunner(verbosity=2)
# To refer your test runner.
```

There are another issues. Here are updated `MyTestResult` and `MyTestRunner`:

```
class MyTestResult(unittest._TextTestResult):
    def addSuccess(self, test):
        super(MyTestResult, self).addSuccess(test)
    def addError(self, test, err):
        super(MyTestResult, self).addError(test, err)
    def addFailure(self, test, err):
        super(MyTestResult, self).addFailure(test, err)
        # To call parent's method use `super`

        # OR qualify with parent class
        # unittest._TextTestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)


class MyTestRunner(unittest.TextTestRunner):
    def _makeResult(self):
        # _makeResult is not called with verbosity, use `self.verbosity`
        return MyTestResult(self.stream, self.descriptions, self.verbosity)
```

Comment: Using the code as is, I get the following error:     File "myreport.py", line 49, in <module>
    testRunner.run(testSuite)
  File "/users/anjangam/pyvenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest.py", line 330, in __call__
    test(result)
  File "/users/anjangam/pyvenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest.py", line 209, in __call__
    result.addError(self,self.__exc_info())
  File "myreport.py", line 10, in addError
    super(MyTestResult, self).addError(test, err)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Comment: Using this line 'unittest._TextTestResult.addFailure(self, test, err)' solves the problem.

Comment: @AnilJ, `super(MyTestResult, self).add...(test, ...)` also should work. I tested both.

Comment: For some reason, it throws above error message I pasted.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to modify (or replace) the default test report that pyunit tool generates?

Comment: @AnilJ, You need to change `add*` methods to write as you wish. To do that, you may need to check `unittest.runner.TextTestResult` code to see how it write status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127939/discussion-between-anilj-and-falsetru).